# JAVA - Difficulty scanning in a TXT file containign a mix of different information

Tags: java

I have a text file containing a list of names and a list of books in this form:

```
5
Prisoner Azkaban
J. k. Rowling
Eragon
Christopher Paolini
Ulysses
James Joyce
Of mice and men
John Steinbeck
War and peace
Leo Tolstoy
4
Craig David
Isabel Campbell
Lee Rinaldo
Bethany Waters
```

The numbers tell you how many"objects" come after the number, starting with a cycle of book name > author, then this pattern stops repeating for the users section where user names are listed.

Here is my attempt at the code:

```
 Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\finla\\IdeaProjects\\Untitled1\\src\\books2.txt"));
    
    int numberOfBooks = inFile.nextInt();


    for (int i= 0; i <= numberOfBooks; i++){
        String bookName =  inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Book name: " + bookName);
        String bookAuthor = inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Book author: " + bookAuthor);
    }
    int numberOfUsers = inFile.nextInt();
    for (int i= 0; i <= numberOfUsers; i++){
        String userName =  inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println("User name: " + userName);

    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Book name: 
Book author: Prisoner Azkaban
Book name: J. k. Rowling
Book author: Eragon
Book name: Christopher Paolini
Book author: Ulysses
Book name: James Joyce
Book author: Of mice and men
Book name: John Steinbeck
Book author: War and peace
Book name: Leo Tolstoy
Book author: 4
```

The book author label i in the wrong place. The loop shouldn't print out the 4 at the end. I would like to be able to read in the list of people at the end. Do you have any suggestions as to why my code won't work? I've tried using next() as opposed to nextline(), but this doesn't solve the problem and only takes the first string from each line.

Comment: You might need to call `inFile.nextLine();` right after calling `inFile.nextInt();` since there is a trailing newline after you grab the int. Right now that trailing newline is being assigned to your first book name maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blank line at the start:

When you use `inFile.nextInt();` it only grabs the int, and does not consume the newline character at the end of the line `\n`.

There are several ways to work around this, one option is to consume the whole line and Parse it to an int, for example:

```
int numberOfBooks = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine());
```

Otherwise, you can simply use a blank nextLine call after using nextInt to use up the rest of the line:

```
int numberOfBooks = inFile.nextInt();
inFile.nextLine();
```

Extra line at the end:

Your loop is running an extra time because of `<=`, remember that loops start from 0, so the correct way is to just use `<`:

```
for (int i= 0; i < numberOfBooks; i++){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want your for loops to go from 0 to < the count or else from 1 to the count as in:

```
for (int i= 0; i < numberOfBooks; i++){
}
```

You had <=, which means you consumed 1 line too many.

Comment: Thank you. I also had to insert inFile.nextLine(); after nextInt() as sororified suggested